# Get local file path in asp.net mvc website

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a solution with two projects : a asp.net mvc website, and a class library. In the website, I have a reference to the class library.

In a method of the class library I need to get the path of a file in my website project (a config file).

I tried :

```
HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath
```

This works but I can't unit test it... Do you have a simple solution for unit tests or an other way to get the path I need ?

I also tried :

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(MyClass)).Location;
```

But I get :

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\.....

What can I use ?

Comment: It sounds like your class library depends on some configuration of physical paths. Usually you would inject this configuration data into any types that needed it in the class library by way of interface. The implementation could be provided in the MVC web app when you configure your container. Sounds like a bit of thought on architecture needs to happen

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sorry, I fact I manage to not use the class library for it... So I have a class inside my website and I need to get the physical path of the website. How can I do it ? (This is a "LoggingService" class and I need the path of the "log4net.config" file)

Comment: HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~") works in that case. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get path of ASP.NET MVC site in the file system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6598264/get-path-of-asp-net-mvc-site-in-the-file-system)

Answer (score 6):

This code did the trick :

```
HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~")
```